# How can i change nicks with Discord Bot with JDA

Tags: java, discord-jda

Im doing a Discord Bot where i need to change the nickname of the user who send the message, for example: Person "A" send a message and i want to change his name to "B".

I have this code, but it doesnt work and i cant find why.

```
public void onGuildMessageReceived(GuildMessageReceivedEvent e) {
    if(e.getAuthor().isBot()) return;

    String[] args = e.getMessage().getContentRaw().split("\\s+");
    System.out.println("lengh: " + args.length);

    if(args[0].equalsIgnoreCase("!verify")) {
        if(args.length == 2) {
            Guild guild = e.getGuild();
            //guild.getMember(e.getAuthor()).modifyNickname("asdsllslslsl").queue();
            guild.modifyNickname(e.getMessage().getMember(), "pepeasd");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to add `.queue()` after `guild.modifyNickname(e.getMessage().getMember(), "pepeasd")`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not queuing the `RestAction` you created. To queue it you'll need to add `.queue()` after the `modifyNickname()` method.

Read more about how `RestAction` and JDA work here: https://ci.dv8tion.net/job/JDA/javadoc/net/dv8tion/jda/api/requests/RestAction.html